# Using libs/dlls compiled in Linux/MinGW in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, mingw, cross-compiling

Update: I get this warning when compiling: multiple '.text' sections found with different attributes

Hi,

I've compiled some libraries (.a and .dll) in Linux using the MinGW Cross Compiler. I can successfully link against them (.a) in Visual Studio 2008. However, when it runs (using .dll), it terminates with the address pointer pointing at empty memory addresses.

Is there a way/a list of things to do that will allow me to use those libraries successfully in VC08?

The cross compiler generates

1. *.dll.a
2. *.dll

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it.

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

You have to have a def file and use the VC's lib tool to generate an import library.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds to me like the two parties are not using the same calling convention, meaning there is a problem in the way the exported dll functions have been defined.

By far the simplest approach would be to define the functions as *extern "C"* by defining the exported functions as follows:

```
extern "C"
{
  int  MyExportedFunction(char *buffer, int length);
  void MyOtherFunction();
};
```

Comment: I had extern "C" in the header import.

Comment: I just noticed. I get 

multiple '.text' sections found with different attributes

when compiling.